# Select entire container div from deep child in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dom-manipulation

Is there a way to target a large container div based on an existing child deep within its DOM tree?

In the following example - can we hide `blockA` based on the fact that a child of `blockA` has a deep child element with an id called `targetA`?

```
  <div class="blockA">
    <span class="title">BlockA</span>
    <div>
      <p id="targetA">
        Delete this whole block, please
        this is a paragraph,
        lorem ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="blockB">
    <span class="title">BlockB</span>
    <div>
      <p>
        this is a paragraph,
        lorem ipsum
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I know that I want to hide div class blockA and not the intermediate div with no class ?

Comment: @vals, what you could try to do is use the `parentElement` property.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp.  This will give you the direct parent element of the target node.  In a bigger example, you would want to find an HTML element that has an attribute that you can look for and traverse accordingly, with the `.closest()` method specified in the answer on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```
child.closest('.parent')
```

From MDN

> The closest() method traverses the Element and its parents (heading
>   toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the
>   provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor.
>   If no such element exists, it returns null.

You can hide `.blockA` element by selecting the `#targetA` element, calling `closest` method on it and passing the class name of the parent element.

```
document.getElementById('targetA').closest('.blockA').style.display = 'none';
```

**P.S.** you might want to guard against `closest` function returning `null`.

#### Demo:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('targetA');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const parent = target.closest('.blockA');
  if (parent) parent.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.blockA,
.blockB {
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 10px 0;
}
p { margin: 0; }
.blockA, .blockB, button { padding: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="blockA">
  <span class="title">BlockA</span>
  <div>
    <p id="targetA">
      Delete this whole block, please this is a paragraph, lorem ipsum
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blockB">
  <span class="title">BlockB</span>
  <div>
    <p>this is a paragraph, lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<button>Hide BlockA</button>
```

Comment: wow.  that was fast, haha.  I will check that out.  Thank you, sir!